# Equivalent of IQueryable in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, iqueryable

I'm used to .Net and LINQtoEntities, especially the IQueryable part which allows to carry a request through different functions before fetching the results.

Does anything like this exist in spring data ? Or any other java ORM ?

Basic example of what I'd like to be able to do :

```
private IQueryable<Todo> GetAll(){
  context.Todos.Where(t => !t.Deleted);
}

public IEnumerable<Todo> GetDoneTodos(){
  GetAll().Where(t => t.Done).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Spring Data's **QueryDSL** integration. Basically, you extend the `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` in your repository interface and it add a `findAll` method that gets a QueryDSL `Predicate` and filter all the results based on that `Predicate`. Suppose we have domain object, say `Greeting`, then we'd have repository like this:

```
public interface GreetingRepository extends QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Greeting> {}
```

Then you can use generated `QModel`s generated by QueryDSL to create a `Predicate` and pass it to our `greetingRepository`. Suppose we're going to filter all the `Greeting`s by one specific user:

```
Predicate filterByUser = greeting.user.eq(someUser);
greetingRepository.findAll(filterByUser);
```

`greeting` is a *metamodel* generated by QueryDSL based on our `Greeting` model.

**Note 1**: You can see how you can integrate Spring Data and QueryDSL [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJyL7_krTKAhWEXSwKHVg4CrQQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fspring.io%2Fblog%2F2011%2F04%2F26%2Fadvanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl%2F&usg=AFQjCNE5Qm8mmiJYX2ZiPhz_huXgQzuptg&sig2=U1zxKewqYgSR4mHW0rkdGg) and see more examples for QueryDSL's `Predicate`s [here](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02.html#jpa_integration).

**Note 2**: `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` also provides `findOne(Predicate predicate)`, `count(Predicate predicate)` and `exists(Predicate predicate)` methods which are useful and self-explanatory, of course.

**Note 3**: You can achieve almost the same thing with `Specification`s but in my opnion QueryDSL has more elegant and readable `Predicate`s.